# Vulkans LunarG validation layer are not working

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

First of all: I already worked a lot with vulkan and had no problems with the validation layers. They worked just fine and complained if I forgot for example to destroy a vulkan handle.

At a later point (did currently code refactoring) it did not work. I kind of forgot how to set up the validation layers.
I isolated a little quick and dirty project (one file) to test if it works isolated:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

HINSTANCE g_hInstance;
HWND g_hWnd;
bool g_running = true;
const char* const APPLICATION_NAME = "debugTest";

VkInstance g_instance{ VK_NULL_HANDLE };
VkPhysicalDevice g_physicalDevice{ VK_NULL_HANDLE };
VkDevice g_device{ VK_NULL_HANDLE };

VkDebugReportCallbackEXT g_callback;
PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT fpCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT;
PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT fpDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT;

void loop()
{
    MSG msg;

    while (g_running)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0u, 0u, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
          g_running = false;
          DestroyWindow(hWnd);
          UnregisterClass(APPLICATION_NAME, g_hInstance);
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        g_running = false;
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        UnregisterClass(APPLICATION_NAME, g_hInstance);
        break;


    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

void win32_createWindow(int nCmdShow)
{
    g_hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    // REGISTER APPLICATION CLASS
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = g_hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = APPLICATION_NAME;
    wc.hIconSm = wc.hIcon;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);



    g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        "Ich bin ein Titel",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100,
        800, 600,
        nullptr, nullptr, g_hInstance, nullptr);

    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, nCmdShow);
    SetFocus(g_hWnd);
    SetForegroundWindow(g_hWnd);

    printf("WINDOW CREATED\n");
}

VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(
    VkDebugReportFlagsEXT                       flags,
    VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT                  objectType,
    uint64_t                                    object,
    size_t                                      location,
    int32_t                                     messageCode,
    const char*                                 pLayerPrefix,
    const char*                                 pMessage,
    void*                                       pUserData)
{
    printf("%s\n", pMessage);
    return VK_FALSE;
}

void vk_init()
{
    // INSTANCE
    {
        VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
        appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        appInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        appInfo.pApplicationName = APPLICATION_NAME;
        appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.pEngineName = APPLICATION_NAME;
        appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

        // LAYER
        std::vector<const char*> layers = {
            "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
        };

        // EXTENSIONS
        std::vector<const char*> extensions = {
            "VK_KHR_surface",
            "VK_KHR_win32_surface",
            "VK_EXT_debug_report"
        };

        VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCInfo;
        instanceCInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        instanceCInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        instanceCInfo.flags = 0;
        instanceCInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
        instanceCInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(layers.size());
        instanceCInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
        instanceCInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
        instanceCInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();
        if (vkCreateInstance(&instanceCInfo, nullptr, &g_instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("INSTANCE CREATION FAILED\n");
            return;
        }

        printf("INSTANCE CREATED\n");
    }

    // DEBUG
    {
        fpCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(g_instance, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT"));
        fpDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(g_instance, "vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT"));

        VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT debugReportCallbackCInfo;
        debugReportCallbackCInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
        debugReportCallbackCInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        debugReportCallbackCInfo.flags = VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT;
        debugReportCallbackCInfo.pfnCallback = debugCallback;
        debugReportCallbackCInfo.pUserData = nullptr;

        if (fpCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(g_instance, &debugReportCallbackCInfo, nullptr, &g_callback) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("DEBUG CREATION FAILED\n");
        }
        printf("DEBUG CALLBACK CREATED\n");
    }

    // GPU
    {
        uint32_t count{ 0u };
        vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(g_instance, &count, nullptr);
        std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> physicalDevices(count);
        vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(g_instance, &count, physicalDevices.data());
        g_physicalDevice = physicalDevices[0];

        printf("PHYSICAL DEVICE PICKED\n");
    }

    // DEVICE
    {
        float defaultQueuePriorities[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

        std::vector<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo> deviceQueueCreateInfos(1);
        deviceQueueCreateInfos[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
        deviceQueueCreateInfos[0].pNext = nullptr;
        deviceQueueCreateInfos[0].flags = 0;
        deviceQueueCreateInfos[0].queueFamilyIndex = 0u;
        deviceQueueCreateInfos[0].queueCount = 1u;
        deviceQueueCreateInfos[0].pQueuePriorities = defaultQueuePriorities;

        // LAYERS
        std::vector<const char*> layers(0);

        // EXTENSIONS
        std::vector<const char*> extensions(0);

        // DEVICE FEATURES
        VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures enabledFeatures{};

        VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceCInfo;
        deviceCInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
        deviceCInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        deviceCInfo.flags = 0;
        deviceCInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(deviceQueueCreateInfos.size());
        deviceCInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = deviceQueueCreateInfos.data();
        deviceCInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(layers.size());
        deviceCInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
        deviceCInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
        deviceCInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();
        deviceCInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &enabledFeatures;

        if (vkCreateDevice(g_physicalDevice, &deviceCInfo, nullptr, &g_device) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("LOGICAL DEVICE CREATION FAILED!\n");
        }

        printf("LOGICAL DEVICE CREATED\n");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    win32_createWindow(SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    vk_init();

    loop();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It does not for me and it should since I did not destroy the logical device.

So what am I doing wrong? I think I activated the correct layers and extensions. I checked [GPU Open: How to use validation layers](https://gpuopen.com/using-the-vulkan-validation-layers/) for that.

Please help me I guess I am just totally blind.

Comment: Are they correctly reported? Are they defined in the registry? I had problems that after driver update they disappear from the registry and I had to add them (I don't remember if reinstalling Vulkan SDK helped or if I had to add them manually). Did You try enabling layers not through code but through environment variable?

Comment: @Ekzuzy I dont know if they are defined in the registry. Where would I find them in the registry?

Comment: @Ekzuzy I did found where the entries should be, but there was no entry with like validation in it.
I reintall the vulkan SDK and check if that helped.

Comment: @Ekzuzy So yes and no. I once deinstalled 1.0, because 1.1 was installed. This deinstallation must have removed all entries from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\Vulkan\ImplicitLayers
Now there are entries, but it does still not work

Comment: @Ekzuzy Does we validation layer not complain, when not destroying the logical device?

Comment: They should complain when You forget to destroy Vulkan resource. Are they enumerated properly when You debug Your code? Did You try enabling them through an environment variable?

Comment: @Ekzuzy I enabled them through an environmental variable and now it complains about something like not enabled a physical device feature, but not about forgetting to destroy a vulkan resource.
What do you mean with enumerating? Checking if the validation layer/extension is supported? I did that in the original project, but not in this tiny one, because I know they are supported on my pc.

Comment: I don't see a vkDestroyDevice in that code above, that's probably the reason for the lack of unreleased resource validation messages. Pretty much all Vulkan resources are tied to the device, so if you want to see those messages you need to properly destroy the device before releasing the debug callback.

Comment: @MisterRecursion If layers complain that a physical device feature is not enabled, than it means layers are working correctly. What layers do You enable? And by enumerating layers I mean checking what layers are returned by `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties()` and `vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Validation layers run when you call a vulkan api function. If you don't destroy the device, the validation layers won't warn you about all the stuff associated with the device that you forgot to destroy.